# Testing contract selfdestruct in Hardhat - Chai matchers

Tags: hardhat, testing, selfdestruct, chai, waffle

I'm writing unit tests for a solidity contract in a Hardhat project and I can't seem to find a selfdestruct matcher. [Solidity Chai Matchers](https://ethereum-waffle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/matchers.html) are a set of helper functions that make testing solidity smart contracts easier. They provide useful functions like `emit` and `reverted` allowing for really clear testing code of the form

```
expect(await contract.someFunction()).to.be.reverted();
expect(await contract.someFunction()).to.emit(contract, "EventName");
...
```

However I couldn't find any matchers for testing the selfdetruction of a contract. I would've expected there to be something along the lines of:

```
expect(await contract.die()).to.selfdestruct();
```

Does anybody know if there is in fact something like this, or if not, how to test for contract's self destruction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the idiomatic way to do this but I managed to accomplish what I was looking for by checking that the contract's code gets deleted after self-destruction:

```js
await contract.die();
expect(await ethers.provider.getCode(contract.address)).to.equal("0x");
```

And to confirm that the contract's balance gets transferred to the specified destination you can just use [changeEtherBalances](https://ethereum-waffle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/matchers.html#change-ether-balance-multiple-accounts)

Answer (score 1):

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

import '@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol';

contract Greeter is Ownable {

  event Transfer(address to, uint256 balance);

  constructor() payable {}

  function transferBalance() public onlyOwner {
    selfdestruct(payable(msg.sender));
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, address(this).balance);
  }
}
```

### in your test.js:

```
const { expect } = require("chai");

describe("Greeter", function() {
  it("Should successfully update contract state after selfdestruct", async function() {
    const {deployer, signer2} = await ethers.getSigners();
    const Greeter = await ethers.getContractFactory("Greeter");
    // deploy contract and send ethers
    const greeter = await Greeter.deploy({value: 1000, from: deployer});
    await greeter.deployed();
    
    // connect the deployer to the contract
    await greeter.connect(deployer);

    // ensure deployer is owner
    expect(await greeter.owner()).to.equal(deployer)
    // check the contract balance
    expect(await ethers.provider.getBalance(greeter.address)).to.equal(1000)
    // check contract get the right code
    expect(await ethers.provider.getCode(greeter.address)).to.not.equal("0x")
    
     await greeter.transferBalance();
    // signer2 can't call the function
    expect(greeter.transferBalance()).to.be.revertedWith('Ownable: not owner')
    expect(await ethers.provider.getBalance(deplyer.address)).to.equal(1000)
    expect(await ethers.provider.getBalance(greeter.address)).to.equal(0)
    expect(await ethers.provider.getCode(greeter.address)).to.equal("0x")
    expect(greeter.transferBalance()).to.emit(Greeter, 'Transfer').withArgs(deployer, 1000)
  });
});
```

I believe this is the only way to test `selfdestruct`, that the contract code is deleted from blockchain.

Please note as per SolidityLang Docs `selfdestruct` will be deprecated starting v0.8.18
https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html#deactivate-and-self-destruct

I hope this helped a bit.